# Create ActiveX OCX control

Tags: vb6, activex, ocx

We are using a system that allows ActiveX extensions through .ocx files.

I need to write an extension to plot some specific proprietary graphics. After lots of searches, I found out Visual Basic 6.0 can create these ActiveX controls and deploy them as .ocx files.

So, is VB6 the only option? I'm reluctant to believe no other options have been introduced by microsoft since 1998.

---

In response to RichieHindle and Arnshea,

During the research, I found out ActiveX controls might be created using C++, but I couldn't find a way to deploy them as .ocx files. Just as dll's.

Comment: Re. DLLs - see my amended answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create ActiveX controls in C++ using Visual Studio 2005 or 2008, via ATL or MFC.  There are wizards to help - the process is relatively painless.  8-)

An OCX *is* a DLL - it's exactly the same, just with a different file extension.  (Pedant's corner: I know the inverse is not true; not all DLLs are ActiveX controls.)

Comment: Why does MS make it so difficult to make a BHO?  Last I foudn I had to use a project from Code Project to get it to work with .NET languages.  It seems like they would make this easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can make ActiveX control in C++ or C with Win32, ATL or MFC projects.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a tool named ActivexPad. Check if it works on your situation.